# Why does my Java 8 stream not work in a Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, java-stream

I am attempting to write my first Maven plugin. The code that is giving me an issue is the following:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    ...

    final List<File> directories = Arrays.stream(directory.listFiles())
                                         .filter(File::isDirectory)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    ...
}
```

The problem appears to be the use of the Java 8 Stream to filter the Array of File objects. This is the error I get when the install phase fails:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project resource-bundler-maven-plugin: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 2921

The non-stream version does work:

```
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    ...

    final List<File> directories = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : directory.listFiles())
    {
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            directories.add(file);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

How do I correctly implement a Java 8 Stream in a Maven plugin?

Added pom contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Resource Bundler</name>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Another example of what *does* work:

```
 List<File> filess = Stream.of(directory.listFiles()).collect(toList());
```

And what *doesn't* work:

```
final List<File> directories2 = Arrays.stream(directory.listFiles())
                                         .filter(File::isDirectory)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Specifically* the issue seems to be with:

```
.filter(File::isDirectory)
```

Also this variation fails:

```
.filter(f -> f.isDirectory())
```

Note also that the following fails:

```
.filter(f -> true)
```

Comment: i don't think the above error is related to java 8 stream, and the above code works fine in my system

Comment: That is the difference between it failing or not though. Perhaps my pom config is wrong?

Comment: Typo `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>` => `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>`

Comment: @Naman Sorry forgot about that typo, have fixed. Problem persists although only with a certain kind of stream.

Comment: With the updated question(`filter` code in the question). Are you sure you get the same error as you did when this question was initially posted?

Comment: You should have maven-plugin-plugin, maven-plugin-annotations using the same versions...